# ModuleNotFoundError when accessing python Flask within jupyter notebook in a virtual env

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I have created an virtual env gcloudenv on my nividia nano running ubuntu. I was able to successfully install flask and required libraries and able to deploy my appengine into GCP from this virtual env. All my work is in python and I was using nano as my editor to get my code up and running. No issues so far.

my virtual env gcloudenv already has all the required packages for flask, jinga etc and I can see them when I run pip freeze.

Then I tried to  work on Jupyter notebook as my code was getting little complicated and I didn't want to write full code and then run.

I already had jupyter notebook installed before creating the virtual env. I also installed jupyter within in virtual env as well. 
 So I followed the instruction to create a new kernel by running the following command:-

```
  (gcloudenv) sunny@my-nano:~gcloudenv/MyApp/mainfolder$ pip install ipykernel
  (gcloudenv) sunny@my-nano:~gcloudenv/MyApp/mainfolder$ ipython kernel install --user -- 
  name=gcloudenv
```

Now, I ran the notebook as:

```
      (gcloudenv) sunny@my-nano:~gcloudenv/MyApp/mainfolder$ 
       /home/gcloudenv/bin/jupyter notebook
```

When trying to import the flask I get the following error:
           ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Note sure what is going on as I getting blanked out.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
!pip install flask
```

in the beginning of your Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But based on my knowledge this is not a good practice. It is all about where the jupyter kernel pointing to. I have solved my problem. see the response below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to solve my problem. Thanks to a wonderful post https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/.

In essence, I had 2 problems:-
1. I did not have a jupyter-notebook within my virtual env. Originally I thought I had it installed but that was incorrect. so whenever I tried to launch one, it was picking the first jupyter notebook it could find in the path. 
The good way to find out which one is it pointing to , is to run which command

```
   (gcloudenv) sunny@my-nano:~/gcloudenv$ which jupyter-notebook
```

For me, that was at:

```
    /home/sunny/archiconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

I had in fact 3 copies of jupyter-notebook on my system. One was probably installed using sudo pip and therefore went into the root folder. Probably not a good thing to do.

So I installed a fresh jupyter-notebook with the following command:-

```
   (gcloudenv) $ pip install jupyter notebook
```

2.Next is to check list of  Jupyter kernels available by running the following from the jupyter notebook ( or from command line):

```
            !jupyter kernelspec list (OR (gcloudenv) $jupyter kernelspec list
```

My jupyter notebook was not able to import flask libraries because it was pointing to a wrong kernel config outside of my virtualenv gcloudenv.

```
        Available kernels:
        gcloudenv    /home/sunny/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/gcloudenv ( correct one)
        python3      /home/sunny/gcloudenv/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

You can determine which python version it is picking by doing a 'more' on the file:-

```
           (gcloudenv) $ 
           /more/home/sunny/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/gcloudenv/kernel.json
```

Once I changed my kernel to point to python3 from within the notebook, it picked the correct path and all the relevant libraries I needed.

In summary when you hit the problem as mentioned above, do the following:-

- check the path of the python ( whereis python or which python)
- check if you are running the 'right' notebook. This is determined by the path and if you have sourced your virtualenv.
- Install jupyter notebook using pip from within your virtualenv( do not use sudo)
- Check the Jupyter kernel. This may be particularly relevant if you have a common jupyter notebook and you want to work with multiple virtualenv.